# Should I HTML encode response of my Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, html-encode

I am designing a Web API which returns JSON as the content-type, the response body could contain characters like `'`, `"`, `<` and `>`, they are valid characters in JSON. So, my question is should I do HTML encode for my Web API response body or should I leave this task to HTML client who is consuming my Web API?

Comment: What if the client has nothing to do with HTML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No; you must not.

You must only escape data if and when you concatenate it into a structured format.

If you return JSON like `{ "text": "Content by X &amp; Y" }`, anyone who reads that JSON will see the literal text `&amp;`.
It will only work correctly for extremely broken clients who concatenate it directly into their HTML without escaping.

In short:

## Never escape text except when you're about to display it

Comment: Hi SLaks, I appreciate your clear answer! when I was asking this question, I subconsciously had the feeling that maybe I should not. Thank you for making me clear on this!

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using? For example, Node.js, you can use restify to handle that very well. You don't need to explicitly encode the data. Therefore, please find a restful framework or component to help you out.