# Remove special characters and replace the same with exact values (e.g. "Jersey+City%2c+New+Jersey" to "Jersey City, New Jersey" )

Tags: c#, regex

I am accessing wcf rest service and getting response as json.

In response , we are getting name of location as `"Jersey+City%2c+New+Jersey"` and so on.

It should be `"Jersey City, New Jersey"`.

so which regex or method can be used so that special characters should be recognized and can be replaced with specific character.

Comment: Have you looked at [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: yes it worked thanks, I used   HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Jersey+City%2c+New+Jersey");

Comment: can you please provide more details what was happening ? why the data is coming is some encoded form

Comment: Because the API is configured to do so? I can't tell without more details, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, actually I was asking about why this encoding and decoding is required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Robin has commented, you can use the static [UrlDecode(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the System.Web.HttpUtility class.

Like:

```
String decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Jersey+City%2c+New+Jersey");
```

Comment: can you please give brief idea about why this encoding and decoding is required.

Comment: If the response of the service is to be displayed inside a browser it should be escaped. See also [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18326252/2655508](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18326252/2655508)